# To disable "Entering Ex mode" in Vim

Tags: vim, ex-mode

I get the following 10X times a day by accident.

> Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.

**How can you disable the combo which causes it in Vim?**

Comment: So glad I found this question... and let me guess, you're a fellow dvorak user, no? :)

Comment: @NikReiman Yes, you are right. I have been using Dvorak now about three and half years, started on October 2008.

Comment: here is a link that explains what that mode is for http://aplawrence.com/Words2005/2005_02_10.html

Comment: Agree with all the answers below, you can simply map it away. But are you sure you want to disable ex mode? It could be quite useful, here's a video by vimgirl showing what you can do in ex mode: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP_xm0VwQa0&feature=youtu.be

PS (I switched to dvorak 5 years ago after my wrist started hurting and then the pain went away. It's an amazing keyboard layout)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This answer is based on @NielsBom's comment 4. October 2012 and on @BrianCarper's answer 13. August 2009.

I think NielsBom is completely right, please see [the article](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).
The command `map` is really evil in Vim and has caused me a lot of problems during years.
I did not realize the thing before NielsBom's comment. So please use the following command instead:

```
:nnoremap Q <Nop>
```

Comment: @NielsBohrn was making a different point: He advised using the **`nore`** version of the map commands to prevent remapping of the right-hand side. In this case that would be `:nnoremap Q <Nop>`, but since the right-hand side is `<Nop>`, remapping is irrelevant.

Comment: The comment has been included in the answer. I selected NielsBom's proposal as an accepted answer here because it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @glts That's an interesting point which I hadn't considered. Thanks for sharing it. At the same time, this `nnoremap` version doesn't really do any harm and may actually prevent problems down the road, for example if someone mindlessly copies this mapping to create another mapping which does not have `<Nop>` as a target. I have certainly been guilty of things like that. For the sake of correctness, simplicity, and cognitive burden, I think we may be better off pretending the `*map` versions don't exist and instead using the `*noremap` versions everywhere, even where they are superfluous.

Comment: Don't forget that it is also possible to enter ex mode with `gQ`. Use `:nnoremap gQ <Nop>` to disable that as well.

Comment: ...and `nnoremap q: <Nop>`

Answer (score 59):

`<Nop>` is meant for use in mapping keys to "nothing".  See `:h <Nop>`.

```
:map Q <Nop>
```

Or put it in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
map Q <Nop>
```

.

Comment: This worked for me from the command mode, but how do you put this in .vimrc?  I tried a bunch of variations, but none of them worked.

Comment: "map Q <ESC>" in my .vimrc worked.  Just don't try putting any comments after on the same line.

Comment: I'd advise always using noremap instead of plain map, see http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html In this one case a map could theoretically never be remapped (I think) but never using a "plain map" is a good strategy in any case.

Comment: @NielsBom Thank You for pointing that out! You saved my day and explained me a lot about my mistakes in Vim. I did not realize it before your comment.

Comment: `q:` (in Neovim) also drops me into ex mode, added `nnoremap q: <Nop>` to fix that

Answer (score 26):

The "combo" is `Q`. To disable it, simply map `Q` to something else:

```
:map Q <whatever>
```

I use `gq`, which is used to format text.

If you don't want it do do anything map it to `<Nop>`:

```
:map Q <Nop>
```

Comment: Thank you! I got used to using `QQ` to reformat my paragraphs, then got on Debian and *BAM!* It was all screwed up.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to map it to something else, just use `:unmap`. If you do have something else in mind, `:map` will work - take a look at the help pages to see the variations to specify what modes the map will be used in.

Comment: `:unmap` does remove mappings, but won't remove the defaults, like in this case.

Comment: I thought the same at first. My answer was originally mentioning `:unmap`, like yours, but then I tried it in my vim and only then I realized it didn't work.

Answer (score -5):

Another, albeit slightly more extreme option, would be to switch to https://neovim.io, which has removed ex-mode entirely, due to no one ever actually using it for anything ever.

Comment: I'm using Neovim and hitting `Q` drops me into Ex mode.

Comment: In some special cases, ex mode can be useful.