# vim shows vim "help.txt" [readonly] 228L, 8578C

Tags: vim

On Macosx in vim (version 8.0) I type :help
Instead of the help opening, I get the message: vim "help.txt" [readonly] 228L, 8578C

My .vimrc is totally empty

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That entering Ex mode is indicative of the issue. Is your TERM environment variable set correctly? Are you sure vim -u NONE does this? Did you hit e.g. Q?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I have to type :vi after that

I found the answer in this post:
[To disable "Entering Ex mode" in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269689/to-disable-entering-ex-mode-in-vim)

Comment: This doesn't make sense... Looks like you're in "ex" mode at startup. If you use vim on an existing file, do you also need to type `:vi` to be able to see it and edit it?

Comment: yes, same, but I installed pathogen. maybe it has something to do with that

Comment: See ["How to debug my vimrc file?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/18609), which should cover plug-ins too.

Comment: no its not pathogen, but you can find out if it's any of your plugins or your .vimrc by starting vim with `vim -u NONE`

Comment: tried out vim -u NONE but the problem still remains